# sql query : show name with all vowels

Tags: mysql, sql

Equatorial Guinea and Dominican Republic have all of the vowels (a, e, i, o, u) in the name. They don't count because they have more than one word in the name.

```
Find the country that has all the vowels and no spaces in its name?
```

You can use the phrase name NOT LIKE '%a%' to exclude characters from your results. The query shown misses countries like Bahamas and Belarus because they contain at least one 'a'

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%u' 
      and name LIKE '%a' 
      and name LIKE '%o' 
      and name LIKE '%i'
      and name LIKE '%e'
      and name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

it does not work. the right answer is "Mozambique"

i hard coded it like "where name like 'Moz'. It worked , but it's cheating

Comment: Why only `name LIKE '%u'` why not `name LIKE '%u%'` and same with other vowels?

Comment: The above approach doesn't work.   If you have a name like `The Republic of Mozambique` it would get ignored; but it shouldn't.  One would have to split out each word onto a new row and check then return them back in a grouped fashion.

Comment: Why doesn't Equatorial count?  it has all the vowels in 1 part of it's name.

Comment: @xQbert I think because that filed would have Equatorial Guinea in it. OP wants where there is no space in the field.

Comment: if true drwierd's response seems sufficient. as would the 1st comment.  Just seems like an odd requirement to me.

Comment: This question is a direct copy from an exercise at sqlzoo.net. https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial#All_the_vowels

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using `and name LIKE '%a%'` for your vowels, this will search the entire string and not just the last letter.

For example:

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%u%' 
  and name LIKE '%a%' 
  and name LIKE '%o%' 
  and name LIKE '%i%'
  and name LIKE '%e%'
  and name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: Use a lower function to not ignore the upper cases . Like lower(name)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM world WHERE name LIKE '%a%' AND
                             name LIKE '%e%' AND
                             name LIKE '%i%' AND
                             name LIKE '%o%' AND
                             name LIKE '%u%'
```

Comment: Your answer is almost the same with the others expect `not like` operator. You should an explanation for your query

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'  Finds any values that ends with "a"

This must be your problem like Ankit is referring to

> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'    Finds any values that have "or" in any
>   position

Answer (score 0):

```
Select first_name from employees where substr(first_name,1,1) in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * FROM world WHERE name  NOT REGEXP '[^aeiou]' AND name NOT LIKE '% %';
```

Comment: square brackets in regular expressions are used as a single space character holder, meaning it matches only one character at a time.